# Make an empty fall like an object?

Tags: animation

I've parented some objects to an empty (to make a TV set) and at a certain point in the animation, the objects must fall to the ground.  Is there a way to make the empty itself fall?

Comment: Since you can't apply rigid body to an Empty, you could always parent to a small transparent object instead.

Comment: Good point!  That worked.